# Extjs - toolbar doesn't appear correctly

Tags: javascript, extjs, toolbar

I have a panel with a bottom toolbar.
when I open my page, sometimes this toolbar is being hidden, as like:

[image]

and when I refresh it appears ok!

```
{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'center',
                    split: true,
                    frame: false,
                    id: 'Panel_1',                  
                    animCollapse: false,
                    frameHeader: false,
                    dockedItems: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'toolbar',       
                            dock: 'bottom',
                            frame: false,
                            id: 'BottomTB',
                            items: [
```

can't figur out what's wrong

Comment: Can you post a bit of your code? or setup an example on jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: You could try using bbar instead of dockedItems.